# How do I add columns to a selector screen (PXSelector)?

Tags: c#, acumatica

I would like to add a couple of columns to the General Ledger > Journal Entry > Batch selection screen. In my specific case, I want to add Batch.CreatedByID and Batch.Description.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1**

Open the selector screen, Ctrl + Alt + Click on the selector screen to inspect it and then choose customize data Fields.

[image: Customize Selector]

Then, click on Selector Columns in the toolbar. There you can add columns by selecting them from the list. Click save in the tool bar, publish the customization, refresh the web site and you selector should be all set !

[image: Add columns]

**Option 2**

To add columns to your selector screen, you need declare a CacheAttached method in the graph of your screen. The method signature follows this syntax :

```
protected virtual void DAC_FIELD_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{

}
```

All attributes that are applied in the original DAC won't be considered anymore, so make sure you put all the necessary attributes on top of that method. (There is another way for version 5.10, see Edit at the end of this post)

```
[PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
[PXDefault()]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Batch Number", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[BatchModule.Numbering()]
[PXFieldDescription]
//PXSelector() still to add
protected virtual void Batch_BatchNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{

}
```

To specify what you need in the selector screen, add a PXSelector attribute to the CacheAttached method. The first parameter is the BQL statement that queries the data to be shown in the selector screen. The second parameter is the one that is useful for us. It is a `params` parameter where you specify all the fields you want as columns in the screen.

```
// Not showing previsouly added attributes for simplicity...
[PXSelector(
    typeof(Search<Batch.batchNbr, 
                        Where<Batch.module, 
                                Equal<Current<Batch.module>>, 
                            And<Batch.draft, 
                                Equal<False>>>, 
                        OrderBy<Desc<Batch.batchNbr>>>),
    typeof(Batch.module),       //This field will be your first column
    typeof(Batch.batchNbr),     
    typeof(Batch.ledgerID),     
    typeof(Batch.finPeriodID),  
    typeof(Batch.status),       
    typeof(Batch.debitTotal),   
    typeof(Batch.creditTotal),  
    typeof(Batch.curyID),       
    typeof(Batch.createdByID),  
    typeof(Batch.description),  //This field is the last column to be shown
    Filterable = true
)]
protected virtual void Batch_BatchNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{

}
```

Here is the complete code sample using a graph extension on `JournalEntry`

```
using PX.Data;
using PX.Data.EP;

namespace PX.Objects.GL
{

    public class JournalEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<JournalEntry>
    {
        [PXDBString(15, IsUnicode = true, IsKey = true, InputMask = ">CCCCCCCCCCCCCCC")]
        [PXDefault()]
        [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Batch Number", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
        [BatchModule.Numbering()]
        [PXFieldDescription]
        [PXSelector(
            typeof(Search<Batch.batchNbr, 
                                Where<Batch.module, 
                                        Equal<Current<Batch.module>>, 
                                    And<Batch.draft, 
                                        Equal<False>>>, 
                                OrderBy<Desc<Batch.batchNbr>>>),
            typeof(Batch.module),
            typeof(Batch.batchNbr),
            typeof(Batch.ledgerID),
            typeof(Batch.finPeriodID),
            typeof(Batch.status),
            typeof(Batch.debitTotal),
            typeof(Batch.creditTotal),
            typeof(Batch.curyID),
            typeof(Batch.createdByID),
            typeof(Batch.description),
            Filterable = true
        )]
        protected virtual void Batch_BatchNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

EDIT : Starting from version 5.10, you are able to merge original attributes with the ones on the CacheAttached method.
You can do it like that :

```
[PXMergeAttributes(Method = MergeMethod.Merge)]
//PXSelector() still to add
protected virtual void Batch_BatchNbr_CacheAttached(PXCache cache)
{

}
```